# How do I get a user's ip address with .NET code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I get a user's IP address with .NET code? I'm using Foo Basic Web Studio IDE that uses ASP.net code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you can that IP address of users.

```
string clientIp = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp))
       clientIp = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string strHostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
string IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Comment: Parhaps using `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName` to retreive the host name would be more straight forward? No need for the HttpContext

Comment: Yes. We get either way @MrPaulch. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MrPaulch - you should post that as a separate answer, for voting purposes. Lets the OP decide which is the best answer to accept. Can't do that with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
  ' Get your Hostname
  Dim szHost As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

  ' Get the host entry for said hostname
  Dim hostEntry As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(szHost)

  ' To get the ip address of the first available net interface:
  Dim ip As System.Net.IPAddress = New System.Net.IPAddress(hostEntry.AddressList(0).GetAddressBytes)
```

Note that `hostEntry` contains the `AddressList` array, listing the IP-Addresses of all active network interfaces.

So you might want to check/filter them for relevance.

Comment: This will retrieve the server IP not the remote client IP. You need to use `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress` as pointed out in the other answer

Comment: Oh this is awkward. I thought the OP meant the 'user' of the server aplication though. (He never even wrote the word 'client')